# Log messages sent to ASL do not appear in query

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I am trying to query log messages sent via ASL and the NSLog wrapper. Running the below code on an iOS 9 device, I get one response from the ASL query and that is the first log string sent via NSLog. The second string "Hello from asl_log" is not returned by the query, even though it goes to the default ASL client. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong with the query or the asl_log call?

```
// Send test data
NSLog(@"Hello from NSLog");
asl_log(NULL, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_EMERG, "Hello from asl_log");

// Query all logged strings
aslmsg query = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
aslresponse response = asl_search(NULL, query);   
asl_free(query);

// Only one message found: "Hello from NSLog"
aslmsg message;
while((message = asl_next(response))) {
    const char *msg = asl_get(message, ASL_KEY_MSG);
}
```

Comment: You have to set ASL_KEY_READ_UID to "-1" as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/16527364/361413.

Comment: Would you like to make this an official answer?

Comment: too shoort ;-) "trivial answer converted to comment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several ways to set `ASL_KEY_READ_UID` to `"-1"`, following the hint of [bk138](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361413/bk138), I finally came up with the following:

```
asl_object_t msg = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_MSG);
asl_set(msg, ASL_KEY_READ_UID, "-1");
asl_log(NULL, msg, ASL_LEVEL_EMERG, "Hello from asl_log");
```

This will make the logs appear in the asl query results.